# Database update script

Tags: php, mysqli

Previous question:

[Database input script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68125/database-input-script)

I'd like this new question reviewed.

```
    <?php
$mysqli =  new mysqli('localhost','root','','yaztor');
if($mysqli->connect_errno >0){
    die( "problem with the connection");


    }


function fetchTableFieldCount($mysqli , $databaseName , $tableName ) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(`COLUMN_NAME`) AS FieldCount FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`= '$databaseName'  AND `TABLE_NAME`= '$tableName' ";

    if ( ! ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) ) {
      die("There is an error with mysql preparation statement".$mysqli->error);
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    if ( $row = $res->fetch_array() ) {
      return $row['FieldCount'];
    }

    return 0;
  }

   function fetchTableFieldName($mysqli , $databaseName , $tableName ) {
    $sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`= '$databaseName'  AND `TABLE_NAME`= '$tableName' ";

    if ( ! ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) ) {
      die("There is an error with mysql preparation statement".$mysqli->error);
    }

    if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
      echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $res = $stmt->get_result();

    while( $row = $res->fetch_array() ) {
     $array []= $row['COLUMN_NAME'];
    }
    return $array;
    return 0;
  }
    function updateDataIntoTable($mysqli, $tableName, $databaseName, $array ,$idFeildName , $idFeildValue) {

        if( ! $tableCoulmnsNames = fetchTableFieldName($mysqli , $databaseName , $tableName ) ){
            die("Error Fetching Table Information");
            }
        $tableColumnsCount = count($tableCoulmnsNames);

        $dataArrayCount    = count($array);

        if ( $tableColumnsCount != $dataArrayCount ) {
          die("Data array does not match table columns count");
        }

        if ( 0 == $dataArrayCount ) {
          return;
        }
          array_push($array,$idFeildValue);

          for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++ ) {
          $string         =  gettype($array[$i]);
          //taking the first letter; example:  string = s, integer = i
          $a_param_type[] =  $string[0];
        }

        for($i=0;$i<$tableColumnsCount;$i++){
            $tableCoulmnsNames[$i] = "`" . $tableCoulmnsNames[$i] ."`";
        }

        $sql = " UPDATE `$databaseName`.`$tableName` SET ";
        $sql .= implode($tableCoulmnsNames , ' = ?  , ' );
        $sql .= ' = ? ';
        $sql .=" WHERE `$tableName`.`$idFeildName` = ? ";
        echo $sql;
         if ( ! $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) ) {
          die("error in preparation " . $mysqli->error);
        }


         //puting data element type 
         array_unshift($array, implode($a_param_type));  

         //refrensing values
         for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array) ;$i++){
            $array[$i] = & $array[$i];
            }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $array);

          if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
          die("Error in executing the query:  " . $mysqli->error);
        }
        return 1;
        }
      $array = array(10, 5 ,"name", "desc", "text", "12-1-2014 01:00", "1");
      updateDataIntoTable($mysqli, "table", "database", $array ,"idFeildname" , $idFeildValue)


    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you must change your die/echo mechanism to something another. Like a throw exception or return a status from the function.

```
if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
  echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
```

And in this part you must not echo error, but return/throw it. Because if you just print it, your code will work further.

Also you must rewrite updateDataIntoTable like this:

```
function updateDataIntoTable($mysqli, $tableName, $databaseName, $array ,$idFeildName , $idFeildValue) {
  $dataArrayCount = count($array);
  if ( 0 == $dataArrayCount ) {
      return;
  }
  ...
}
```

This is called [guard statement](http://blog.mafr.de/2009/06/12/a-case-for-guard-clauses/). Better to keep all returns at top or bottom function.